# What does "No Native to Message converter set" mean?

Tags: delphi, soap, delphi-2007

I need to talk to some web service and thus I imported the WSDL. I now try to call it but it reports this exception: `No Native to Message converter set`
Very, very irritating, especially since I have no permission to post code snippets from this service here. Still, have to try... Does anyone have some suggestions about how to fix this error?

---

The error is generated in rio.pas in the function TRIO.Generic. This line:

```
  if not Assigned(FConverter) then
    raise Exception.Create(SNoMessageConverter);
```

For unknown reasons, FConverter is set to nil, thus the exception is generated. This happens even before the request is sent. Nothing is sent to the service, since Delphi crashes even before it can call the service.

---

WSDL Import options, checked options:

- One Outparam is Return
- Unwind literal params
- Generate destructors
- Warning comments
- Map string to widestring
- Generate verbose information about types and interfaces
- Ignore porttypes with HTTP bindings
- Do not emit unused types
- Validate enumeration types
- Import fault types
- Import header types
- Process included and imported schemas
- Generate class aliases as class types
- Process nillable and optional elements

Actually, My system is new, Delphi was installed about 3 days ago and importing this WSDL was the first thing I did, basically using these default settings.

Comment: Please list your Delphi version, and whether you've applied any fixes, such as patching D2005 with D2007 SOAP libraries. Also indicate which version of the WSDL importer you used, and which options.  Also indicate the document type.  Why? These are usually the first things people will recommend that you change one way or the other.

Comment: Chris, isn't the delphi-2007 tag not clear enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SoapUI consume the WSDL and make a mock service.  Point your app at your SoapUI mockservice, and you can capture your outbound requests.  Now you can turn around and submit those requests to the service and see the response.  That should give you an idea of where the message is coming from. i.e. is it coming from Delphi's SOAP library as a result of something that it doesn't understand, or is it coming from the web service itself, as a result of something that IT didn't understand in your request?

Alternately, you can do this in Delphi:  Intercept the inbound/outbound XML by leveraging the RIO_BeforeExecute/RIO_AfterExecute events of your HttpRIO object.

If your traffic is http (harder with SSL but possible) you can also intercept with Fiddler2.

Once you have the raw XML, submit requests with SoapUI, and see what you get.  You may find that your requests need "tweaking", or if everything looks fine in SoapUI, you may need to tweak the responses before de-serialization.